# Matplotlib list object

Tags: python, matplotlib

If I create a list object such as 'a' and then I can plot out `a[0]` against `a[1]`.

```py
a = [ [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 45] ] 

plt.plot(a[0], a[1])
```

[image: plot1]

Why can I not do the below to have a second plot against `a[2]`.

```py
plt.plot(a[0], a[1:])
```

The docs say this

[image: docs]

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `plot(x, y)`, the condition `len(x) == len(y)` should be met. The doc clearly mentions **columns**. You are trying to plot rows. Try this instead...

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [ [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 45] ] 

plt.plot(a[0], np.transpose(a[1:]))
```

Comment: Thank you. I now get it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's first understand what is x values and what are y values:

In this array:

```
a = [ [1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 45] ]
```

if you want to assign `x` as `a[0]` i.e.  `[1,2,3]`, then after passing them to a function say **f**, we should get the corresponding `y` values;

which means

y1 = f(1)
y2 = f(2)
y3 = f(3)

so for 3 x-values we would need 3 y-values

But when you pass `a[1:]` as y-values, you only select `[[10, 20, 30], [15, 30, 45]]`, i.e. only 2 values, `[10, 20, 30]` and `[15, 30, 45]`, there is no value available for `y3`.

So what you can do is either add value of `y3` in your list `a` or transpose the y values from a shape of (2,3) to (3,2)

```
plt.plot(a[0], list(zip(*a[1:])))
```

Y - values now look like:

```
>>> list(zip(*a[1:]))

[(10, 15), (20, 30), (30, 45)]
```

y1 = (10,15)
y2 = (20,30)
y3 = (30,45)

Output:

[image]